# Django settings, templates and SQLite data don't update

Tags: python, django, server

I deployed my django website to Hostgator, but now I can't see any changes in the website when changing the files. The only changes that happen are in static files, like CSS and JS, but changing the templates won't make any difference to the shown HTML.

The database works fine: I can add and remove entries with Django admin in the site and that will take effect in the HTML. But if I run manage.py or even delete completely the SQLite file, nothing happens.

Running the same django project locally on my machine works fine.

It's as if those files were in cache or something like that. I tried lots of things, but nothing works.

Comment: clean  cache, try another browser... you can try these tricks to debug before

Comment: Are you re-compiling your files?

Comment: I was trying to solve this for literally two weeks. When I decide to post a question here I find the answer immediately after. Turns out the website was in another directory, not the one I was updating. Really dumb error that took me weeks.